# Jquery datepicker showing a rogue popup

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This issue appears to happen only  in Chrome.

I am using the jquery datepicker function to set a couple of default dates but as soon as the dialog box opens, I get a 'default' datepicker calendar popup in top left hand corner of my screen for no month, the title bar is not there for the popup one either. If I now select either of the below datepickers, the rogue datepicker disappears.

If I remove the defaulted date lines then I do not get my rogue datepicker

```
$('#fromdate').datepicker("setDate", '-6M');
$('#todate').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Found a way round my issue but it's not very elegant, found the name of the div that was displaying (ui-datepicker-div) and set it's style to display:none in top of my html. But still not sure why it is happening and why it only happens in Chrome

Comment: Just noticed the same Chrome specific issue on the system I work on. It coincided with our last code release but it seems it may be a new Chrome issue vs something we did on our side.

Comment: have you find solution for this . as i am facing same issue on my client site http://e-hotelspro.com in chrome. thanks